# Speed up terminal. Disable Mac OS X background processes

Tags: terminal, speed

I use my mac for programming. Cursor movement I strongly feel should be almost instantanious, on mac it isn't. (Vimtutor I now do in virtalbox to get fast cursor movement).

Before I start to change settings I need some advice. Which background processes should I disable and which is better left as they are?

Comment: First off, don't go around killing background processes without a clue to what they do. Second, you should *really* provide more information. Is this a problem in all applications? Do you have the same problem in other user accounts on the same machine? What terminal software do you use? Does it happen in Terminal, in iTerm2? What background processes are activated for your user account (check System Preferences, Accounts, Login Items and ~/Library/LaunchAgents)?

Comment: Ok. I try some myself and. delete my question therefore.

Comment: Don't delete your questions mate. If you're lucky a mod can rollback. Other might find what you typed helpful

Comment: @jarleif:  What you did was edit the question and replace it a completely different statement.  This doesn't delete the question.  What is now in its place is e-litter.  If you really want to delete the question, there should be a delete link available for you below the question's tags.

Comment: Jarleif, if you figured out what's wrong, please share it with us. I reverted your post to its original state. There should be a link "delete" right below your post, otherwise please click "flag" to request deletion by a moderator instead

Comment: Information noted. I will do that from now on.